How to create a link to an anchor on the main page from an iframe embedded in the main page?
With HTML, how to create a link to an anchor on the main page from an iframe embedded in the main page?
The iframe is called and  inserted and from the main page ( iframe is hosted in Github with a github domain link)
I tryed locally this sample bellow , it's work . But on the prod serveur when i click on the link nothing happend.
index.html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page principale</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="section1">Section 1</h1>
    <p>Ceci est la section 1.</p>
    <h1 id="section2">Section 2</h1>
    <p>Ceci est la section 2.</p>

    <iframe src="iframe.html" width="100%" height="300px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

iframe.html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contenu de l'iframe</h1>
    <a href="#section1" onclick="parent.location.hash='section1'; return false;">Aller à la section 1</a>
    <a href="#section2" onclick="parent.location.hash='section2'; return false;">Aller à la section 2</a>
</body>
</html>


Using JavaScript for this was unnecessary to begin with - a elements do have a target attribute. "But on the prod serveur when i click on the link nothing happend." - have you checked what the browser console has to say? There is probably something in there saying that top level navigation was restricted.

Have a look at https://iframe-resizer.com as it solves this problem for you.

Finnally it's look like to be a security restriction at the CSP level. Maye be set in the web host. By default an Iframe don't autorize Javascript to an other domain (CSP).
